# Django ORM: How to query secondary database which is in read-only mode and no reference in model.py file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

I want to query secondary database which is basically a production database. Currently I am using direct query but want to use ORM.

My current models.py file looks like below. Here user is providing TABLE name. For simplicity consider TABLE is "SERVER_LIST".

```
from django.db import connections

# Create your models here.
def my_custom_sql(TABLE):
    with connections["my_oracle"].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select * from {0} where server = 'XYZ';".format(TABLE))
        row = cursor.fetchall()

        return row
```

Database entry:setttings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    },
    'my_oracle': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'xyz:1234/ABCDB',
        'USER': 'ABC',
        'PASSWORD': '1234'
    },
}
```

I want to run same query using Django ORM. Can someone help how to connect to secondary database and create models.py file for this database. I refer to this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) but it imports model.py file which i dont think is possible in my case as database is already existing and in read-only mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DATABASES` variable in your `settings.py` file should look something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': DEFAULT_DB_CONFIG,
    'slave': SLAVE_DB_CONFIG,
}
```

and when you are using ORM and want to query a table, you can use `using` interface like below:

```
SampleModel.objects.using('slave').all()
```

Check documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: what is SampleModel here. Thats exactly where I am stuck.

Comment: That is the model corresponding to the table you want to run your query against. If you just have the table and there is no corresponding model for that table, you need to create a model for that table before using the django's ORM.

Comment: can u plz guide how to create models.py file for it.

Comment: Please check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: i tried above link but it is listing the table in sqllite database not my_oracle. I can't make my_oracle as default database as local sqllite need to be default to save migration settings.

Comment: Did you try `inspectdb` command like this: `python manage.py inspectdb --database my_oracle` ?

Comment: it just gave one line "from django.db import models"

Comment: thanks for helping this far. vote up. In case you get to know how to create models.py file let me know.